# Dissolving hydrated vs non-hydrated salts

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

in chemical catalogs, salts are often sold in hydrated and non-hydrated versions.  Like sodium sulfate anhydrous and sodium sulfate decahydrate.  I tried dissolving the anhydrous and it didn't dissolve very easily, instead it clumped.  I'm wondering if I would have had easier dissolving with the hydrated form, but I don't have it to check.  Is it often the case that easier dissolving occurs with the hydrated salts with water complexed to the ion?

Comment: Usually hydrated salts are quite easily dissolved in water. I have often observed this phenomena, for example with $\ce{Na2CO3}$. But I don't know whether it is systematic.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice, that is helpful. I was setting up an electrolysis experiment and figured sodium sulfate was the best salt to use, but purchased the anhydrous and the clumps had to be mechanically broken up by tapping with a glass stirring rod.

Comment: On the other hand, there are some salts of *supernal* solubility. Read "The Endochronic Properties of Resublimated Thiotimoline" by Asimov, https://archive.org/details/AstoundingScienceFictionv41n1/page/n120/mode/2up <grin>